# Using INSERT in SQL, syntax for INT

Tags: python, mysql, sql

How do I use the `INSERT INTO` query with the following data types:
`INT` and `AUTO_INCREMENT`?

```
INSERT INTO table2 (class,name) VALUE (%s,%s)
```

...works with strings only.

Comment: Could you please tell which RDBMS you are using, and also the programming language? And please show the entire line(s) of code. You should be able to cast `int` and `DateTime` variables to strings for sql queries.

Comment: Whatever the programming language that you're using, it would be advisable to use bind parameters instead of string formatting: `INSERT INTO table2 (class,name) VALUE (:name,:value)`. http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: `AUTO_INCREMENT` isn't a data type. Sounds like you're asking how to `INSERT` values into a table with a column set to `AUTO_INCREMENT` - correct?

Comment: @Yuck, yes that is what I'm asking.

Comment: @Shredder using MySQLdb and Python

Comment: You don't need to specify the autoincrement field in your INSERT statement. If you do, MySQL will insert the value you provided. If you don't (or if you specify it as NULL), then it will use the next available value.

Comment: @Marki555 thanks- what is the syntax. I get errors INSERT INTO table2 (autoincrement_id,name) VALUE (' ',%s).

Comment: @Tom I think 'VALUE' should be 'VALUES'

Answer (score 1):

You can try [`%d`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) for digits.

As for the autoincrement column, if you omit it from the `INSERT` statement, then the database will [automatically fill it](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/example-auto-increment.html) with the next value.